# Finding the Measure of the Angle Created by Two Vectors

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The question is as follows:

> Find the angle formed by **u** and **v**, given that **u** = [-1, 0, 1] and **v** = [0, 2, -2].

I thought about using a formula related to the Law of Cosines. 
$$\cos(C) = \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{ab} $$

The variable $a$ would be the magnitude of vector $u$ and the variable $b$ would be the magnitude of vector $v$. I got the values of 1 and $2\sqrt{2}$, respectively.

I remember that the third side of a triangle can be found by subtracting the two vectors, so I thought of doing $u - v$ (which would be denoted as side $c$). I did that and got $|u - v| = \sqrt{13}$.

After substituting the values to its corresponding places in the Law of Cosines formula, I got:
$$\cos(C) = \frac{1^2 + (2\sqrt{2})^2 - (\sqrt{13})^2}{1(2\sqrt{2})}$$
The value that I get does not allow for me to find the $\arccos$ of it--I get an error message on my calculator.

I want to know what I am doing wrong, therefore, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $v\cdot w=\|v\|\|w\|\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $v$ and $w$.

Comment: There is a $2$ in the Law of Cosines formula that you seem to have lost. The denominator should be $2ab$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Thank you so much for catching that error! I found that the angle measure should be $135^{\circ}$. Thanks again!

Comment: @geo_freak Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by definition $$\cos\theta=<u,v>/(|u| |v|)$$

in this case you obtain  $$\cos\theta=-1/\sqrt2$$